# proper way of dto objects when consuming web service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My application is divided into 3 projects

- domain
- ui.web.mvc
- webservices.webapi

inside domain I have two models

```
Car
Engine
```

my webservices projects references domain object in order to retrieve data.
If mvc projects sends data using complex viewmodel or dto to the webservice and 
webservice then maps that model to the domain one, is it normal to think that
that viewmodel or dto exist on both projects (`webservices`, and `mvc`)?

Comment: Domain objects AND a web service which retrieves them? Weird setup. Why not abstract the web service as a persistence implementation (i.e. repository)? It should return/store domain objects. I don't see the point of DTOs in such scenario. And View Models most def don't have place in your persistence layer.

Comment: my repository is insde domain project. Do you suggesting that I move repository to separate project? And my view models are inside mvc layer not persistance layer.

Comment: What does the WS do?

Comment: WS (mvc) consuming webservice, manages data.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*(Not pictured: the MVC will also need to either reference the concrete implementations, or use XML configuration, in order to setup IoC container)*

For starters, your MVC application should not know about the Web Service. It should be abstracted behind an interface (Dependency Inversion principle).

```
public HomeController(IRepository repository, IService service)
{
    this.repository = repository;
    this.service = service;
}
```

My assumption is that the Domain Objects also have persistence annotations. This is the most common case, because the other two options are a) Anemic model or b) Domain Model, which are both extreme. If the assumption is correct, both the Repo and the Service should work with Domain Objects. I don't see place for the DTOs you mention.

The 'pattern' is simple: retrieve Domain Object (either from Service or Repo), invoke some business logic on it, pass it back to the Service/Repo.